# cts search ignoring index order with cts:element-attribute-reference date

Tags: xquery, marklogic

### Background

I'm using a cts search in MarkLogic and it is not sorting by the passed sort option.

For example the following produces unsorted results

```
xdmp:document-insert("/test/test1",<test attrDate="2016-1-10"></test>);
xdmp:document-insert("/test/test2",<test attrDate="2015-1-10"></test>);
xdmp:document-insert("/test/test3",<test attrDate="2017-1-10"></test>);

cts:search(
  xdmp:directory("/test/", "infinity")/test,
  cts:true-query(),
  (
    cts:index-order(cts:element-attribute-reference(xs:QName("test"), xs:QName("attrDate")), ("ascending"))
  )
);
```

This returns the following:

```
<test attrDate="2016-1-10">
</test>
element 
<test attrDate="2015-1-10">
</test>
element 
<test attrDate="2017-1-10">
</test>
```

So the correct results but unsorted.

### Question

How can I sort by an attribute in a MarkLogic cts query?

### Further Background

I have an index set up on that attribute, here is the config:

[image: attrDate index config]

(This can index be created at http://localhost:8001/ > summary > YOURDATABASE-content > Attribute Range Indexes > Add, although I added it via Roxy)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this was a simple data issue (which I found in the last 5 seconds before posting this)

2016-01-10 is the 10th of January 2016

2016-1-10 is a malformed string that MarkLogic just ignores

Comment: Other issues that can happen (but not with the data from the question) `<a><test attrDate="2016-1-10"></test><test attrDate="2020-1-10"></test>` searching for `\a\test` the index for the wrong `test` may be used (seems the index is on a per document not per element basis?)